# how to use tr to delete a octal characters sequence?

Tags: text-processing, sed, tr

I'm trying to delete this:      `--More--` from a .dat file, this is a fragment of the file to give an example:

```
Device ID: N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL)
  IP address: 148.228.4.192
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/1,  Port ID (outgoing port): Ethernet7/19
Device ID: CIRC_INF_IDF1
  IP address: 148.228.107.252
Interface: FastEthernet0/20,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
  IP address: 148.228.107.252
Device ID: CIRC_INF_IDF3
  IP address: 148.228.107.250
 --More--         Interface: FastEthernet0/23,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
  IP address: 148.228.107.250
Device ID: CIRC_INF_IDF2
  IP address: 148.228.107.251
Interface: FastEthernet0/22,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
  IP address: 148.228.107.251
Device ID: SEP1CAA0711CFBE
 --More--           IP address: 148.228.199.103
Interface: FastEthernet0/2,  Port ID (outgoing port): Port 1
Device ID: SEP1CAA0711CD67
  IP address: 148.228.199.154
Interface: FastEthernet0/5,  Port ID (outgoing port): Port 1
```

Using a Hex text editor I've identified the non-visible characters 
[image]

Now I'm trying to delete the whole sequence of characters but I haven't had succeeded,

those are my tries:

```
tr -d --More--           < tabladetallada.dat >temporaltabla.dat

tr -d '\015' '\012' '\20' '\055' '\055' '\115' < tabladetallada.dat >temporaltabla.dat

sed 's/--More--␣//' tabladetallada.dat>tabladetallada2.dat

tr -d ' --More-- ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H        ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H' < tabladetallada.dat >temporaltabla.dat
```

Any help?

Thanks.

this is how it looks in vi:

```
Device ID: N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL)^M
  IP address: 148.228.4.192^M
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/1,  Port ID (outgoing port): Ethernet7/19^M
Device ID: CIRC_INF_IDF1^M
  IP address: 148.228.107.252^M
Interface: FastEthernet0/20,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1^M
  IP address: 148.228.107.252^M
Device ID: CIRC_INF_IDF3^M
  IP address: 148.228.107.250^M
 --More-- ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H        ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^HInterface: FastEthernet0/23,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1^M
  IP address: 148.228.107.250^M
Device ID: CIRC_INF_IDF2^M
  IP address: 148.228.107.251^M
Interface: FastEthernet0/22,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1^M
  IP address: 148.228.107.251^M
Device ID: SEP1CAA0711CFBE^M
 --More-- ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H        ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H  IP address: 148.228.199.103^M
Interface: FastEthernet0/2,  Port ID (outgoing port): Port 1^M
Device ID: SEP1CAA0711CD67^M
  IP address: 148.228.199.154^M
Interface: FastEthernet0/5,  Port ID (outgoing port): Port 1^M
Device ID: SEP1CAA0711D11A^M
  IP address: 148.228.199.4^M
Interface: FastEthernet0/10,  Port ID (outgoing port): Port 1^M
Device ID: SEPece1a985bb74^M
  IP address: 148.228.199.21^M
Interface: FastEthernet0/12,  Port ID (outgoing port): Port 1^M
Device ID: SEPf84f5794c5c4^M
  IP address: 148.228.199.23^M
Interface: FastEthernet0/11,  Port ID (outgoing port): Port 1^M
Device ID: SEP1CAA0711D276^M
  IP address: 148.228.199.102^M
 --More-- ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H        ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^HInterface: FastEthernet0/9,  Port ID (outgoing port): Port 1^M
Device ID: SEPece1a985b5d5^M
  IP address: 148.228.199.24^M
Interface: FastEthernet0/14,  Port ID (outgoing port): Port 1^M
Device ID: SEP1CAA0711497C^M
Interface: FastEthernet0/4,  Port ID (outgoing port): Port 1^M
Device ID: SEPf84f5794c8c2^M
  IP address: 148.228.199.22^M
Interface: FastEthernet0/3,  Port ID (outgoing port): Port 1^M
Device ID: Circulo_Camaras4^M
 --More-- ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H        ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H  IP address: 148.228.101.5^M
Interface: FastEthernet0/24,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet1/0/24^M
  IP address: 148.228.101.5^M
```

Comment: Note to answerers: the markdown rendering eats the characters. If you want to test your solutions, click on the [edit] link and copy the example directly from the question.

Comment: What do you want to delete exactly? The `---More---` + unprintable characters? Or should we also delete the spaces?

Comment: `tr` doesn't delete sequences. It can delete all occurrences of characters in a given set, which would help remove the backspace characters, but you'll need something more (like `sed`) to remove the sequence `--MORE--`

Comment: thanks to all of you, I've solved this problem, i used tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' to delete the "garbage " and then sed 's/--More--␣//  to delete that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/^[ ]*--More--.*\x8//' -e 's/\xD$//'
```

---

- Instead of writing `s/ */../` my personal preference is `s/[ ]*/../` as it makes the `*` visibly attached to the atom on it's left when it's a space/TAB.
- `GNU sed` has the hex matching facility with the `\x`*hexdigit* sequence.

Comment: Why are you using a character class for a single character? Why not just ` *` (that's a space before the asterisk)? Oh, and it would be great if you could explain the `\x` notation.

Comment: I had got a different solution, but then I noticed this is better.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually Terdon's solution is much superior. Why? If there's even one ^H towards the end of line, then this sed will eat up the whole line and leave you with only --More-- :-( When I saw that [^\s\w] I realized the shortcoming of my sed methd. HTH.

Comment: Well, superior after you fixed my stupid mistake, you mean ;). Anyway, please remember to vote when you see good (or bad) solutions. You've been here for almost 3 months now and haven't cast a single vote! Votes are essential for pushing bad answers down and good answers to the top.

Comment: I was referring to the `sed` method. And I am not able to vote uptil now. S.E. doesn't allow me.

Comment: @RakeshSharma what? Why not? Do you get some kind of error? You can vote up [as soon as you get 15 reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) and downvote at 125. Given your very fast rise in reputation, could it just be that you hadn't tried since the first days? You should be able to vote normally now. If not, if you still have trouble, please let me know and we can see how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to think the other way around. Instead of trying to define the characters you don't want, define the ones you do want and remove anything else:

```
sed 's/--More--[^ a-zA-Z0-9]*//' file
```

That will delete the string `--More--` and 0 or more characters after it that aren't a space, a letter or a number. Depending on your data, you might have to tweak that set a little (e.g. also allow `_` or whatever you need).

Now, the first `--More--` in your question seems to contain contains backspace characters (octal 010, Hex 7, ASCII `\b`), so you could also just do:

```
perl -pe 's/[\b]//g' file
```

Or, to remove the `--More--` as well:

```
perl -pe 's/--More--[\b]+//g' file
```

Comment: There's a run of spaces in the middle of the backspaces (to overwrite the `--More--`, I suppose), so maybe something like `s/ --More-- \x8+ +\x8+//g`

Comment: @ilkkachu or just `s/\x8+//g`, then.